# Stack Careers invitation leads to NOT FOUND when logged in with Facebook

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I'm using my Facebook login for my WPSE and SO account, so I thought I should create an account on careers using the same. But I follow the invitation I received and try to log in with my Facebook credentials, it leads me to this:

[image]

Any idea how I can link the careers profile to my existing accounts? Or just log in with FB for that matter?

Comment: Does that for some other OpenID providers as well

Comment: This should be fixed now, can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works nicely, I just made my profile there!
Thanks! :)